# Dependency injection with asp.net core for properties

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In spring boot you have the ability to inject properties or environment variables into your code so that they are available upon start time. If they are not set then the application fails upon starting.

Is there anything similar in ASP.net core? Basically I want to inject properties/environment variables and they are not set then the app should fail at startup and notify this.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core DI system, you can only inject a dependency via the constructor but you can use another DI System like  AutoFac, Ninject or Lamar to use Property injection.